# Глобально задать каталог для изображений. Возможно ли?

Tags: php

товарищи! У меня такой вопрос: возможно ли где-то (в конфиге, например, наком-нибудь) прописать глобально путь до картинок, чтобы при создании статьи каждый раз не писать `<img src="/Public/img/1.jpg" />`, а просто имя файла?

Comment: А каким образом статьи создаются?

Comment: Ну просто в админке форма с input для заголовка и ключевых слов и textarea для тела статьи

Comment: Надо хотя бы какой-то cke editor прикрурить, не двухтысячные ведь... А так-то, если путь не меняется можно писать просто картинку (в texarea) и уже при выводе на страницу добавлять путь

Comment: А как добавлять? Может быть как-то в контроллере прописать или в виде вывода статьи?

Comment: Ну я же не знаю как у вас вывод происходит.. Нам вообще ничего неизвестно о вашем приложении. Можно хоть в контроллере, хоть при выводе добавлять

Comment: Скажите, а как добавить? Это наверное какая-то регулярка будет? Я просто даже синтаксически не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Да хоть переменную задайте, а потом юзайте по всему проекту

Comment: @DaemonHK, да, но как?

Comment: @Linne я понял для чего Вам это, но зачем Вы думаете об этом? Текстовый редактор сам подставляет пути. Либо в настройках к нему указывается основной путь до картинок

Answer (score 0):

Не надо этого делать. 
Путь всегда должен быть однозначным и абсолютным.

А чтобы не "писать каждый раз", путь должен подставлять онлайн-редактор

Comment: А у меня нет редактора ))))) Я не стал прикручивать, у меня просто суровый textarea :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $path = "/Public/img/";
    echo '<img src="'.$path.'1.jpg">';
    echo '<img src="'.$path.'2.jpg">';
    ...
?>
```

Comment: Нельзя php в текстареа запихать) Только html

Comment: @Linne в вопросе ни слова о textarea =/

Comment: Я понимаю, но как внедрить переменную $path в атрибут src? Статья создаётся в textarea, теги img находятся непосредственно в теле статьи

Comment: @Linne предоставляйте в вопросе сразу всю информацию, если хотите получить правильный ответ... Прикрепите пример img в textarea как вы размещаете..

Comment: <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p><img src="/Public/img/7.jpg" alt="Elliptorhina" /><p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>